# Gas or Electric trolling motor?

Tags: fishing

What are the important differences between a gas and electric trolling motor for fishing in a small jon boat?  I'm primarily concerned on the impact the the actual fishing (as opposed to any discussion on the environmental impact of fuels).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The noise at first glance would seem to be the major concern, but in reality it is the vibration of the combustion engine that will increase your area of disruption.  Fish are pretty sensitive to vibration and vibes can travel a long way in water.

I am of course assuming the prop design and speeds are similar.  If you were to use gas, vibration dampening would be a good idea, but if you have the option I would go with electric.

Comment: Thanks!  I was myself thinking of noise and forgot about the whole lateral line thing with fish and vibrations.